# Make a time IntervalSlider

Tags: date-and-time, slider

I want to make a time interval slider with an initial setting of (10:00:00 Mar. 8 2015,  12:30:00 Mar. 8 2015) and which varies from 00:00:00 Mar. 8 2015 to  22:30:00 Mar. 8 2015 with a granularity of 5 Minutes.

I tried using `IntervalSlider` in *Mathematica* 10 like this:

```
IntervalSlider[{DateString[{2015, 3, 8, 10, 0, 0.}], 
      DateString[{2015, 3, 8, 12, 30, 0.}]}, {DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 0, 
        0, 0.}], DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 22, 30, 0.}], 
      Quantity[5, "Minutes"]}]
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need work with an interval slider in terms of [`AbsoluteTime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteTime.html) values because such sliders only work with numeric objects. Here is a demonstration where a interval slider has the behavior you want.

```
With[{
  min0 = AbsoluteTime @ DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 10, 0, 0.}],
  max0 = AbsoluteTime @ DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 12, 30, 0.}],
  minT = AbsoluteTime @ DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0.}],
  maxT = AbsoluteTime @ DateObject[{2015, 3, 8, 22, 30, 0.}]}, 
  Manipulate[
    DateString /@ span,
    {{span, {min0, max0}, "Interval"}, minT, maxT, 5 60, 
      ControlType -> IntervalSlider}]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Cool! It is done.

Answer (score 2):

In version 10.1, try this:

```
Manipulate[
   TimelinePlot[
       {Interval[{ToString[myBegin], ToString[myEnd]}] -> "My range"},
       PlotRange -> {DateObject[{1940}], DateObject[{2020}]},
     Ticks -> {DateRange["1940", "2020", Quantity[5, "Years"]]}
  ],
 {{myBegin, 1950, "Begin"}, 1950, 2014, 1},
 {{myEnd, 1960, "End"}, myBegin, 2015, 1}]
```

Comment: +1, but note as `Begin` slider increases, the `DateTicks` start to overlap.  Maybe you can answer my Q: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78821/timelineplot-range-specification-alignment

Comment: @alancalvitti I think there must be a bug in `TimelinePlot` which prevents the "obvious" implementation of `PlotRange`.  (I just got 10.1 an hour ago, so haven't explored all the power and limitations of `TimelinePlot`.  However, `Ticks->All` in my example prevents overlapping (but marks by seconds).

Comment: @alancalvitti  I figured it out.  See my revised solution.