# Using Manipulate function on time series data

Tags: manipulate, time-series

I have a list of data `{{date,real},{date,real},...,{date,real}}` and I want to use the [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) function on the data.

How do I put the data in a form that [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) will work on it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because is hard to understand what you are asking (we can't read your code) and you have a simple syntax problem that you could have found in the documentation. Here is consider helpful to include the code in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) so we can copy and paste your code. Please help us to help you.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with this data, therefore it is difficult to give any examples.  Please specify your question more clearly.

Comment: Possible [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78759/3066)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2014"];

Manipulate[
 Block[
  {x = DatePlus[data[[1, 1]], t]},
  DateListPlot[
   data
   , Epilog -> Line[
     {
      {x, Min@data[[All, 2]]}
      , {x, Max@data[[All, 2]]}
      }]
   ]
  ],
 {t, 0, QuantityMagnitude@
   DateDifference[First@First@data, First@Last@data]}]
```

[image]